# Remove blank lines in minted

Tags: minted

Is it possible to remove blank (empty) lines in `minted`, and gobble multiple blank lines to a specified amount, like the `emptylines` option in `listings`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{listings}
% I want something like the emptylines option
\lstset{language=[Visual]{C++},emptylines=1}
\begin{document}
\begin{minted}[frame=single]{cpp}
int i = 0;


i++;
\end{minted}
\begin{lstlisting}
int i = 0;


i++;
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Marco, it seems I have programmed to much C++ today.

Comment: Af far I know you can `globbe` the star of lines or disable numbering of blank lines (`numberblanklines=false`) but wihout removing lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `minted` package uses `fancyvrb` behind the scenes. This package doesn't have a build-in facility to skip blank lines. It is possible to add a test to skip blank lines, for example

```
\begingroup
\makeatletter
\catcode`\^^M=\active
\gdef\FancyVerbGetLine#1^^M{%
  \@nil
  \FV@CheckEnd{#1}%
  \ifx\@tempa\FV@EnvironName
    \ifx\@tempb\FV@@@CheckEnd\else\FV@BadEndError\fi
    \let\next\FV@EndScanning
  \else
    \def\FV@Line{#1}%
    \ifx\FV@Line\@empty % Test added here
      \def\next{\FV@GetLine}%
    \else
      \def\next{\FV@PreProcessLine\FV@GetLine}%
    \fi
  \fi
  \next}%
\endgroup
```

Dealing with picking particular numbers of blank lines is more tricky: Id be tempted to simply go for `listings` or edit the code source rather than try to alter this.